# Changing discriminator value produces empty migration

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I attempt to rollback using custom Discriminator in TPH hierarchy and start using default ones.

I removed `builder.HasDiscriminator().HasValue("CustomValue");` from all the entities configuration. However when I generated migration the `Up` and `Down` methods are empty, only the `ContextModelSnapshot` is being updated with new discriminator values.

Without updating discriminator values the old data will be corrupt. How to prevent that?

Comment: Are you only removing the `HasValue("...")` or also the `HasDiscriminator()` call?